# Why are Integers from ADODB.RecordSet being converted to Date when written to Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with Excel 2010.

Using VBA I am populating an `ADODB.RecordSet` from a MySQL database then writing the results of the RecordSet into a range of cells in the workSheet. All the cells in the worksheet are using the 'General' format.

In the Recordset there are two fields of type Integer.

When writing to the worksheet if I only include the start cell (as shown in the code below) everything works as expected and all integer values are written correctly to the worksheet.

The code that reads from the database and writes to the worksheet is here:

```
SqlString = "SELECT * FROM ......"

Set Connection = New ADODB.Connection
Connection.Open ConnectionString

Set Recordset = New ADODB.Recordset
With Recordset
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .CursorType = adOpenForwardOnly
    .LockType = adLockBatchOptimistic
    .Open SQLString, Connection
    .ActiveConnection = Nothing
End With

With Sheet11
    .Range("AD33:AM47").Clear
    .Range("AD33").CopyFromRecordset Recordset
End With
```

However, if I include the full range when writing the Recordset to the worksheet the format of the cells containing the integer values get converted to Date, even if I specifically set the format of cells within the Macro.
The code in this case is:

```
[...]
With Sheet11
    .Range("AD33:AM47").Clear
    .Range("AG33:AG47").NumberFormat = "General"
    .Range("AI33:AI47").NumberFormat = "General"
    .Range("AD33:AM47").CopyFromRecordset Recordset
End With
```

This results in a date of '01/01/1900' + the actual integer being displayed in the cells of the worksheet where I would have expected to see the integers.

For example:

- integer = 10
- formatted cell contains `10/01/1900`

What is causing this re-formatting to occur?

Comment: I don't know that this will fix the problem, but instead of General, try formatting as `"@"` before dropping the records. I've done plenty of ADODB work in excel, but I've only ever see it drop records in as text, so I'm at a loss here.

Comment: Thanks for the input but no joy I'm afraid. The cells are still getting reformatted to Date.

Comment: Interesting.  I would suggest you run this with the Locals Window on and step through it to see which line is changing the format type.  Also, if you know you are using numbers, why go with General, out of curiosity?